# Jquery mouseover not working when elements overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out something please help. I have two elements, one is inside of the other.
Both have mouseover listener.

The problem is, only the wrapper element's listener is fired, i can not make the other listener to work, even if i set the inner element's z-index higher.

I was thinking on jquery exclude selection ? But im sure there is a much simpler and better solution.

Here is the code:

```
#outer{
    width:500px;height:500px;position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#inner{
    padding:10px;position:relative;top:50%;left:50%;
    z-index:2;
}

<div id='outer'>
    <span id='inner'>&nbsp;</span>
</div>

$('#outer').mouseover(function(){ console.log('outer'); });
$('#inner').mouseover(function(){ console.log('inner'); });
```

Why the z-index not working in this case ? Im sure the situation would be the same if i float the two object on each other, or one would be the document object, and the other is a div inside.

Comment: the inner event is fired in jsfiddle (I'm using Chrome).  http://jsfiddle.net/WBLwL/  What browser are you using?

Comment: On a separate note... it's odd how you have your inner set up as relative and outer set up as absolute. Usually it would be reversed so the inner is absolutely positioned relative to the outer.  What's your intention there?

Comment: Its completely my bad. i had a console.clear() right before both of the logs, and i did not figure that when the inner listener gets called, the outer listener will be called too. So before i could see 'inner', it called the outer's function which cleared the console and put out 'outer' (actually i still dont understand why is that happening. Why does the outer gets called when i move the mouse to the inner ?? ). btw relative-absolute was not intended.

Answer (score 0):

you can trick the things.
first add a `class` to your `outer` div and secondly instead of using `mouseover` event we use `mouseenter` event and bind this event on that class.

like this

```
$('.outer').mouseenter(function(){ console.log('outer'); });
```

and instead of using `mouseover` event on your `inner` div use `hover` event.

In `hover` event first `function` will call on `mouseover` and second on `mouseout`.

The trick is , on first function we remove the class of parent div i.e. `outer` div and on second function we add that class again and trigger the `mouseenter` event of parent div.

like this

```
$('#inner').hover(function(){
    $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.removeClass("outer");
    console.log('inner'); 
},function(){
    $parent.addClass("outer").trigger("mouseenter");
});
```

that is how you can achieve your task.

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X6SRA/1/)